# How to share all the core files and folders in angular 6 which are common for all the apps?

Tags: angular, architecture, directory

I am developing angular 6 apps in my local window machine.
A separate copy of core files and folders (which are common for all the same version of angular app) are set each time a new app is created.

I want **all the core angular common files and folders to be shared across all the apps** developed under the same drive.

Now my question is:

->The **directory structure** and all the **required settings** needs in such sharing during

```
  1. development 

  2. testing

  3. deployment and migration

  4. version upgrade
```

Let me clarify my question with an example.

Suppose, "e2e" and "node_module" are the core directories for angular 6 and should not be changed at any cost for any app. Now every time I create a new app these 2 directories will be get set for each copy of the apps newly created. If we have a way to share the same copy of these 2 directories among all the apps (we create in angular 6 under the same drive) then what would be the directory structure?

Now its not all about the development only. The individual app(which was developed by sharing common core files and directories) needs to be migrated from developer server to the testing server and further to be deployed into production server. So next question is how'll we do that in this case?

Again with minor angular version upgrade, if our app needs any up-gradation(angular up-gradation) ever, then how could we do that?

Comment: @Dave : here i meant library modules

Comment: Have you seen this: https://blog.angularindepth.com/creating-a-library-in-angular-6-87799552e7e5

Comment: @DeborahK : Thanks for the reply. It's a good article. But it was not what I am looking for. There, it says "How to create a new library in angular 6". But my question is how to share the built in directories or files (angular core files, which should not be changed in any app and get set every time you create a new app) among all the other apps developed under the same drive. I edited my question to clarify with an example. Please re-read and let me know if you need any further clarification.

Comment: The e2e folder *Should* be different for every application you create as it is the folder for your end to end testing. The node_module folder is automatically created for you when you use the `ng new xxx` command

Answer (score 1):

to my understanding any angular APP is essentially a angular module. you can keep a global structure that has all the default folders that get generated through angular CLI and then add a shared folder for all your shared files... every time you need to create a new app, just add a top level module.. i found a very nice article to support my point of view .kindly check for yourself..

and thank you for this question on my youtube channel

https://medium.com/@motcowley/angular-folder-structure-d1809be95542